# effective way how find all files that matches the regexp

Tags: java, spring

I have an regexp( this regexp is not static but is input from configuration - can be any valid regexp ) and i need to find all files that matches this regexp.

Example of the regexp `/home/users/[a-zA-Z]+/[a-z].png`

So far i am using:

```
 Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("/"), Collections.emptySet(), Integer.MAX_VALUE, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
                try {
                    File f = file.toFile();
                    String absoluteFileName = f.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/").replace("C:", "");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(absoluteFileName);
                    if (m.matches()) {
                        files.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                LOGGER.error(String.format("Error visiting %s exception: %s", file, exc));
                if (!(exc instanceof AccessDeniedException)) {
                    throw exc;
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
```

This does find all files matching the regexp however it is too slow and not very effective. Is there any better, more efficent way how to find these files? Im open to external libraries

Comment: Splitting the regex over File.separator would let you traverse less directories but it can be problematic as the character can be inside character classes, lookarounds, part of an alternation, etc.

Comment: If you have the liberty of changing the input pattern's format, consider using a list of regex (one per directory nesting level). That way you can at each level restrict the subdirectories to search in to those that match the pattern so far.

Comment: @Aaron could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your solution is slow because it tests every single file on your system. It needs to realize that looking for a file `/a/b/c` inside `/x/` is a waste of time and that it should not traverse the content of that directory. But you need a way to find out at each level whether subdirectories are "in the right way". If your input regex is `/a/b/c` as in my previous sample it's easy : split it over `/`  use the three resulting parts as regexs while you traverse down the file tree. But regexs can use `/` in other contexts, such as `/[^/]*/` or `(/a/b|/b/c)`  where splitting wouldn't work

Comment: So I'm suggesting you could change your input format from a single regex (e.g. `/home/users/[a-zA-Z]+/[a-z].png`) to a regex per directory (e.g. `/home, /users,  /[a-zA-Z]+, /[a-z].png`, maybe without the slashes) which you would match one by one while descending the file tree

Comment: but if the user inputs regexp that would not be dividible by "/", e.g /home/user/[a-zA-Z\/]+.png, this should match any .png file under /home/users/ , in any depth so you could not do something like you have mentioned.

Comment: You regret that my solution doesn't allow for a way to traverse any number of dirs, such as the regex `/home/users/.*\.png` would, potentially matching `/home/users/a/b/c/d.png`, right? That's indeed a limitation of my solution, although that could be fixed by expanding your input format a little more and letting it accept a custom token (maybe `**` ?) that your code doing the search would interpret not as a regex but as a request to start searching recursively from that point

Comment: unfortunately, this will be used by internal teams, and adding custom tokens for regexp will confuse the hell out of UAT or anyone ( as i try to make it as simple as possible from user usage point of view ) :/

Comment: How about two inputs then, the first one being a directory in which you'll search recursively (replacing `Paths.get("/")` in your posted code), and the second the regex matching the filename? Might be an acceptable compromise between performance and usability depending on your use cases

Comment: @Aaron indeed, that was my initial solution however it was deemed as too "unintuitive" for people that may use it, and thus its last option. However it seems it will be the best option. Another option would be dynamicly detect the start of the regexp and put that dir as base.But in worst case scenario ( such as regexp in my previous comment ) it would still be ultimately slow :/